# Remote debugger for iOS? I need to debug a accessory

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, remote-debugging

I'm testing a hardware accessory, with not emulator.

Because that, I can't debug and at the same time connect the accessory, because in both cases is necessary a cable connection.

So, exist any way to use a remote debugger in iOS? Or at least, send NSLog output remotely?

Comment: [This blog](http://yellowfieldtechnologies.wordpress.com/2010/10/08/ios-debugging-with-hardware/) talks about a solution for remote debugging with an accessory.

Comment: There is a handy library you can add that will email your logs or save them in a file you can pull off later. [Lumberjack](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, it is not possible to run an iPhone application in the debugger over Wi-Fi. It is however possible to run Instruments over Wi-Fi, which was specifically introduced for the use case of developing hardware accessories.  See the release notes for iOS 3.1, in which this feature was introduced: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iPhoneSDK-3/.